# How to send data from android to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: android, asp.net, json, web-services, c#-4.0

I have created one web site and android applcation and I have used backed as SQL Server 2008.
I have used web services to display data from server to android application for that i have used JSON and ksoap library and it is working fine. I can display data from server to android. But now i want to store data from android application to SQL Server 2008. So anyone please tell me the step or how i can do that. Please help.

Comment: "android post request" type that on Google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to SQL Server database through webservice.

Here is the sample code to call the webservice.

```
String url = "your_webservice_URL";

 try 
 {
    HttpPost loginHttpPost   = new HttpPost(url); 
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();          

    MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
    multipartContent.addPart("parameter1", new StringBody(value1));
    multipartContent.addPart("parameter2", new StringBody(value2));
    loginHttpPost.setEntity(multipartContent);

    HttpClient objHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = objHttpClient.execute(loginHttpPost,localContext);
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: ok...but can you tell me how i can write asp.net web service to insert data??

Comment: actually i have created the web service for display data by calling the stored procedure. but i dont know how to insert data from web service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379936/how-to-invoke-an-asp-net-web-service/13380353#13380353

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example source code to **`Connect Android to SQL sever via WCF using JSON`**

Example :

[1. Connecting Android to SQL Server](http://www.mediafire.com/?ocmzcc4jl9blsrh)

[2. Get Data using XML](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/)

[3. Get Data using JSON](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/)

[- Inserting Data into database using WCF Service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/inserting-data-into-database-using-wcf-service/)