# Service to connect to SQL Server with Android

Tags: android, sql-server, eclipse, service

I'm creating my first android app. My app works in the following way:

1. User log into the app.
2. The login details is on an online server which is SQL Server 2008 R2
3. The server will return data to the app and the data the data will be stored on the app's database.

The problem I am facing is how should i connect to **Sql server database**. I researched on this topic and found out that I need to use some service. Can someone suggest as to what service should i use? A normal .NET web service, WCF service or Java Service.

I also need to know how to consume this service in my app.

Softwares I have with me:

- Visual Studio 2008
- SQL Server 2008 R2.
- Android Development Kit & Eclipse
- SQLite

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212419/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-sql-server-2008 once check this url it near to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend the Asp.Net Web API for this:

"ASP.NET includes ASP.NET Web API for creating rich REST-ful Web Services that return JSON, XML, or any kind of content the web supports! ASP.NET Web APIs can provide data services to mobile apps like Windows Phones, iPhones, Android and more. ASP.NET Web APIs can be used in any ASP.NET Web Application, including ASP.NET MVC, Web Forms, or Web Pages – it's all One ASP.NET."

http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: WebAPI requires .net 4.

Answer (score 3):

Just to get you the general overview here;

You do not connect your (Android) app directly to the remote SQL database/server. Android, nor any other mobile platform, provides a steady and reliable interface for doing so.

Secondly, what you want to make indeed is a (REST) web-service.
As long as your needs are simple (passing along a bit of simple data between your app and your database) this means nothing more then having some web language take up some GET or POST variables and putting them in the database for you. And the same the other way around.

You can do this in any (web)language. The choice for language might be most influenced by the server you want to run in on, and what languages it already supports.

Comment: I'll be using VS 2008 .NET framework 3.5. I tried creating a WCF Service. But i could not import `System.ServiceModel.Web`. Do i need to upgrade to VS 2010?

Comment: Sorry i'm not into windows servers and .net :)